# Exercise 2.35 in Lee's introduction to topological manifolds

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and for every $p\in X$ there exists a continuous function $f:~X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=\{p\}$. Show that $X$ is Hausdorff.